# Conflict between defining index signature and extending interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have two interfaces, `human` and `bird`. As you can see, all content in `human` is wrapped inside value `_human` key. Same for `bird`.

```
interface human{
    _human: {
        hands: number,
        name:string
    }
}

interface bird{
    _bird: {
        wings: number,
        name:number
    }
}

interface IEntity extends human, bird{ }

function foo(x: IEntity) {
    let keys = Object.keys(x);
    console.log(x[keys[0]].name);
}
```

To access their content, in function `foo`, I do following:

```
let keys = Object.keys(x);
x[keys[0]].name
```

But I get error: `element implicitly has any type IEntity no index signature.`
To solve this if I replace keys `bird` and `human` with `[key:string]` respective interfaces, I get this error:

```
Property 'human' of type '{ hands: number; name: string; }' is not assignable to string index type '{ wings: number; name: number; }'.
```

I would like to know if there is any workaround other than creating the flag in `tsconfig` to not to report implicit errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that the return of `Object.keys` is `string[]`, and when you try to access an `IEntity` with a string index, you get the error you're seeing. You can fix this by telling typescript that the type of `keys` isn't `string[]` but the more specific type `(keyof IEntity)[]`.

So for your example:

```
function foo(x: IEntity) {
    let keys = Object.keys(x) as (keyof IEntity)[]; // Note the cast here
    console.log(x[keys[0]].name); // x[keys[0]].name is inferred as string|number, no errors
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But the same logic doesn't work for `type IEntity = human|bird`. Can you explain why?

Comment: `type IEntity = human|bird` is not the same as `interface IEntity extends human, bird {}`. But `human & bird` would be the same. It doesn't work for the union case because the keys of a union type is the set of *shared keys* between the two. Since those types have no keys in common, `keyof (human | bird)` ends up as `never`.